# How to generate image from tensor array output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I have a tensor array output from an image segmentation process. I need to generate the output image from this tensor array. Since I am a beginner at image segmentation tasks, I go through some articles but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: if you want to save image use PIL, just to visualize you can use matplotlib. What is the shape of your tensor?

Comment: @rajkumar_data image at shape (1, 3, 1024, 1024)

Answer (score 0):

With the `plt.imshow()` function from Matplotlib, you can convert your Tensors to image.

Please refer this code snippet for visualising your tensors :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
img = [[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255]]

#Insert your tensor here.
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)

# Reshape if required as per the desired shape
#img = tf.reshape(img,shape=(3,3,1))

plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img)
```

You can play with the image by modifying the shape and the RGB values.

Output:

[image: ![enter image description here]